# strings command in command line tool is not responding

Tags: macos, command-line-tool

on Mac machine, I am looking for a specific string in any non-text using coreservicesd command tool. If I am searching for the word delegate for example (which I know the word is there), I type:

```
$ strings /my/path/to/my/file.cs | grep Delegate
```

The window freezes. it keeps on and on without a message telling me if it is successful or not.

It has been running for over half an hour and the file is only 435 bytes!

I've tried other files with other searches like .dll files, .app files and .exe... same fate!

Comment: What happens if you just run `strings` without pipe into `grep`?

Comment: Try `strings -a yourfile`

Comment: `strings` is typically used with **binary** files; is `file.cs` an object or binary file?

Comment: I have also tried it with various different files: .app, .dll, .exe... same behavior: hanging and nothing is happening!
There must be something wrong with it, not installed correctly or damaged... is there an alternative?

Comment: 7 years later, and I am reproducing this on the mac too. Hmm. 
`which strings` gives `/usr/bin/strings`. File shows a Mach universal binary.